# MVC 5 + $Post() function not working after hosted on server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have developed an application in MVC5. Onclick of a link on the View below code gets invoked -

```
// Code in View File 

$.post('../ControllerName/FunctionName',  //this is your url
            {
                id: image,

            }, function (data) {
                alert("Successfully published");
            }
            ).error(function () {
                alert("Failed to publish");
            });


//Code in Controller

[HttpPost]
    public void ISPPDF(string id)
    {}
```

Issue that i am facing is the ISPPDF() function gets invoked when i run it through visual studio.However after i hosted my application on server it does not seem to call the function..

I feel there is some issue with the path i have specified -

i also tried specifying path the below ways but no luck!

```
 /ControllerName/FunctionName
 ControllerName/FunctionName
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: install IIS on your local machine and try running the application through that - will allow you to replicate the issue locally. Have noticed that VS configuration of IIS is different to the "real" IIS.

Comment: You should use `Url.Action` to generate the link.

Comment: What error are you getting in the browser and use `'@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")'`

Comment: "../ControllerName/FunctionName" this URL is likely to be invalid.

Comment: Also, look in the console (or better yet, network tab) of your browser tools and see what it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your post method is in view file

$.post('../FunctionName',{ id: image,}, function (data) {  alert("Successfully published");}).error(function () {alert("Failed to publish"); });

Comment: While this solution might get the job done for this specific case, it's strongly advised not to hard-code URL values. Instead use `Url.Action` as I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You should never hard-code URLs in MVC.

Instead use `@Url.Action`.

```
$.post('@Url.Action("FunctionName", "ControllerName")',  //this is your url
```

If you need to send parameters, you do it like this:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("FunctionName", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.ID })',  //this is your url
```

And there are two important reasons why I recommend this:

1. The chances of mistyping the URL are huge. This Questions proves it, the OP mistyped the URL.
2. `Url.Action` takes into account your route. If your route changes, `Url.Action` will know how to build the correct URL. This way you will not have to go through multiple views to change all the hard-coded values.