# issue with asp.net webApi routing with angularjs. (Multiple actions were found that match)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have read almost everything. applied all solutions. still nothing is working.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "ApiWithAction",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
```

Web api Sorting.cs file

```
[ActionName("pcc")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(PccModel pcc)
{
     return Ok()
}

[ActionName("sortBy")]
public IHttpActionResult PostSortBy(SortByModel sortByModel)
{
            return Ok();
}
}
```

calling web api from angular controller .js file

call to sortBy...

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Sorting/sortBy',
            data: sortByModel,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
       .success(function () {

        }).error(function() {
        });
```

call to pcc

```
return $http.post('/api/Sorting/pcc', data);
```

In both call, same multiple action method error comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "ApiWithAction",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

before

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

for more info [see this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#order)

Comment: You should also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/27227596/4304188 for an explanation on why it's such a bad idea to hardcode URLs in MVC.